# To concatenate the binary matrix of different size

Tags: matlab

Let **Data** be a non-negative matrix of of size **n x 2**.

Now the **Data** matrix is divided into **Data_1** of size **n1 x 2** and **Data_2** of size **n2 x 2**. A row in **Data** may belong

1. Either **Data_1** or **Data_2**
2. **Data_1** and **Data_2**
3. Neither **Data_1** nor **Data_2**

Corresponding to **Data_1** and **Data_2** matrix we have binary matrix **DataIndicator1** of size **n1 x k1** and **DataIndicator2** of size **n2 x k2** respectively.

Now i would like to create a new binary matrix for **Data** of size **n x (k1 + k2)** such that

1. When a row from **Data** belongs to either **Data_1** or **Data_2**, the row in the resultant binary matrix is from **DataIndicator1** or **DataIndicator2** respectively with other entries as 0.
2. When a row from **Data** belongs to both **Data_1** or **Data_2**, the row in the resultant indicator matrix is from **DataIndicator1** and **DataIndicator2** concatenated together.
3. When a row from **Data** doesnt belongs to both **Data_1** or **Data_2**, the row in the resultant indicator matrix should be 0

Can any one provide me the efficient way of doing it in matlab?

Comment: How do you know which rows of `Data` belong to `Data_1` and `Data_2`?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, your input is `Data`, `Data_1`, `Data_2`, `DataIndicator1` and `DataIndicator2` and you want to code something which finds matches between the first three to stich together the information from the last two into a new variable `DataIndicator`... is that right?

Comment: I think your question could profit from a small example...

Comment: the answer from Jonas meets my requirement

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there are no repeated rows in any of your arrays, there is a straightforward answer using [ISMEMBER](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/ismember.html):

```
[tf1,idx1] = ismember(data,data_1,'rows'); %# find where the rows of data_1 are in data
[tf2,idx2] = ismember(data,data_2,'rows'); %# find where the rows of data_2 are in data

n = size(data,1);
k1 = size(dataIndicator1,2);
k2 = size(dataIndicator2,2);

binaryMatrix = false(n,k1+k2);
binaryMatrix(tf1,1:k1) = dataIndicator1(idx1(tf1),:);
binaryMatrix(tf2,k1+1:k2) = dataIndicator1(idx2(tf2),:);
```